# Old Steel Rebuild

Tags: chain

I'm trying to rebuild a 1966 Schwinn Continental. The chain and derailleur are different than anything that I have seen. The derailleur itself seems to be fine along with the wheels. I say wheels because that is exactly what they are. The chain has seen better days though. My question is: Where do I find a chain that will work when on this type of derailleur that has no teeth?

Comment: What do you mean "no teeth"? Some pictures would help.

Comment: I have seen a few derailers where the idler wheels were either round (no teeth) or where the teeth were pretty well worn off.  The only real problem with this is that the chain will slide on the wheel and eventually wear it down (faster than would be the case if the wheel turned with the chain).  No special chain should be needed.

Comment: Sounds like a 3/4/5 speed rear cassette?  You'll want a 5 speed, 3/32" chain with 1/2" pitch.  Most likely you mean "jockey wheels" instead of wheels in your question - these can be purchased new for a couple dollars as long as originality is not a priority, and they're a simple swap.   Please use the EDIT link below your question to add one or two clear photos of the problem, and we can help more.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [1966 Schwinn Catalog](http://schwinncruisers.com/catalogs/1966.html) the Continental had a Schwinn Sprint derailleur

> **Schwinn Continental**
>
> 10-speed
> Designed for high performance. Excellent quality sports equipment on Schwinn's diamond type steel frame. Sprint derailleur, 38 to 96 gear, quick-release hubs, center-pull caliper brakes, leather racing saddle, Schwinn Puff high pressure road racer 27" x 1 1/4 tires. Radiant Coppertone, Sky Blue, Violet.
>
> 321 Continental Sports, 21" frame...$81.95
> 323 Continental Sports, 23" frame...$81.95

This derailleur was [apparently](http://www.disraeligears.co.uk/Site/Schwinn_Sprint_derailleur.html) the Huret Allvit model, made in France

> Chain width: 3/32”

In other words, a standard 5 speed chain. You can get one from any local bike shop, or online.

Comment: $81.95?  Bargain!